# Electroweak theory Landau pole

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, weak-interaction, electroweak

It is known that non-asymptotically free theories like Quantum Electrodynamics or Scalar field with quartic interactions ($\phi^4$) have a landau pole which mainly investigated through lattice simulations of these theories.
And it is generally considered that it's a sign of incompleteness in the theory.

But what about the electroweak theory, after all, it is considered that weak and electromagnetic forces merge above unification energy into one force?

Does the electroweak theory have a landau pole? Has anyone modeled the $SU(2)$ + $U(1)$ + $\phi^4$ sector?

Comment: There is an extensive literature on the renormalization of the gauge-Higgs coupled theory.  There references here https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.5868 might help.